# Support User Time Zone in Embedded Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

Google Calendar's embed code inserts a "ctz" variable in the URL to set the appropriate display time zone, however I'm working with more than 500 users on a global website and trying to keep everyone clear on scheduling (non-paying language learners, otherwise I'd just hire an expert).

Does anyone have advice on how to set the user's time zone based on their IP address? I've already scanned the questions quite extensively through the day.

Comment: Well since I'm using SquareSpace (right, I know it's not everybody's favorite...) PHP and Rails won't integrate. Posting additional info in the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [JSTZ](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jstimezonedetect) library e.g. via cdnjs by including a script tag in the  like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.7/jstz.js"></script>
```

Then put a script tag just before the closing  tag that:

1. Tags the container of the embedded calendar iframe with an id like
   'calendar-container'
2. Breaks the iframe embed code into two segments
   around the timezone param in the url
3. Gets the timezone name from JSTZ
4. Sets the innerHTML of the container to that rebuilt iframe tag.

So if your calendar embed iframe tag looks like:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showPrint=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;mode=WEEK&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=somecalendaridentifier%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23AB8B00&amp;ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Your script would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var timezone = jstz.determine();
  var pref = '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showPrint=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;mode=WEEK&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=somecalendaridentifier%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23AB8B00&amp;ctz=';
  var suff = '" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
  var iframe_html = pref + timezone.name() + suff;
  document.getElementById('calendar-container').innerHTML = iframe_html;
</script>
```

Comment: This is great.  I would suggest you mention  adding `<div id="calendar-container"></div>` like @Marek Rzewuski said and I would also uri encode the timezone. 
`var timezone = encodeURIComponent(jstz.determine().name()); var iframe_html = pref + timezone + suff;`

Comment: Works like a charm! If you want to see a PR where I add this to a website, check out: https://github.com/JuliaLang/www.julialang.org/pull/1124/files#diff-192a0fa3456b30ddf0afdbec688ae76e0c8bde32ee8096dbc82e87f262382509

Answer (score 4):

Your solution has worked wonderfully. My final code was like this

HTML (from [Marek Rzewuski's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1872607/marek-rzewuski) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42461423)):

> ```
> <div id="calendar-container"></div>
> ```

JavaScript (modified from [sheive's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475965/sheive) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32511510)):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.4/jstz.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var timezone = encodeURIComponent(jstz.determine().name()); 
 var pref = '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=agenda&src=somecalendaridentifier%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=';
 var suff = '" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
 var iframe_html = pref + timezone + suff;
 document.getElementById('calendar-container').innerHTML = iframe_html;
</script>
```

I simply put together all relevant answers on this page.

Or, with ES2015 and without the unneeded JSTZ dependency:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone 
const html = `<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=agenda&src=somecalendaridentifier%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=${timezone}" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>`
document.getElementById('calendar-container').innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

Comment: I am new to this page and saw that my final question was eliminated, related to applying this solution on incognito windows (calendar doesn't show up there). Why was that?

Comment: By using  var timezone = console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone) I eliminated the need for the library jstz

Answer (score -1):

Someone suggested taking a JavaScript library called [JSTZ](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/) and adding it dynamically to the embed code of Google Calendar. Fortunately, it appears the Google Calendar uses that same standardized IANA time zone codes as browsers (yay good data!) thus avoiding a massive SWITCH statement.

> var timezone = jstz.determine();
>   timezone.name(); 
>   "America/New_York"

But I still can't figure out how to get this done. Can someone help take this past the last mile?

Answer (score -2):

Works fine. Have to add:

```
<div id="calendar-container"></div>
```

in html

Comment: Could you please specify what you're saying works fine and where you would add the div id?

Comment: Answer "sheive" works fine: "Use the JSTZ library e.g. via cdnjs by including a script tag in the like..."  and so on. But you have add HTML line: <div id="calendar-container"></div>